# How to throw Filepond error manually from javascript to keep original validated UI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filepond

Is it feasible to throw a Filepond error from javascript so that everything is done within the original FilePond UI?

I have Filepond Instance which l validate image types and file size.
I'd also like to validate file length, but as I understand, length validation is not supported by Filepond so I've done it manually via js. I get image width and height by loading DatUrl from Filepond. I'd like to throw an error while comparing image width and image height.

#### image.vue

```
<template>
  <file-pond
    name="test"
    ref="pond"
    label-idle="Click here, or drop files here..."
    accepted-file-types="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"
    label-file-type-not-allowed="change file types"
    file-validate-type-label-expected-types="{allButLastType}  or {lastType} is allowed"
    label-max-file-size-exceeded="file size limit exceeded"
    label-max-file-size="max file size 15MB"
    max-file-size="15MB"
    @addfile="addFile"
    :disabled="isDisabled"
    :allow-remove="false"
  />
</template>

<script>
async addFile(error, file: any) {
  if (!error) {
    try {
      const base64DataUrl = file.getFileEncodeDataURL()
      await Image.load(base64DataUrl).then((image) => {
        if (image.width > image.height && image.height < 1000) {
          # would lile to throw filepond error here
        } else if (image.height > image.width && image.width < 1000) {
          # same 
        }
      });
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error)
      this.failedAddFile()
      return
    }
    this.$emit("add-file", this.file)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, it's not possible to manually throw an error with the current Filepond API.

Comment: Isn't this the plugin you're looking for? https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-validate-size/

Comment: I want to throw error from javasript. I'd like to add some logic from what the plugin offers